# Jasmine test, function not being called

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I'm testing a validator, that makes a call to a service, if zero is returned, it will return an error object.

I've created a spy for the service, with returnValue, which seems to work fine, but I'm having difficulty executing the validation function and returning the value.

What I've ended up doing is creating a spy for the function I'm testing which I don't think I should be doing.

The validator function:

It takes a service as a parameter and uses internally

```
static require(service: Service): ValidatorFn {
   return (formGroup: FormGroup): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
      const checkedCount = state.currentCount();
      if (checkedCount === 0) {
          return  {
            'isNotChecked' : true
          };
        }
      return null;
    };
  }
```

The test, that works:
As I said I really don't think I should be spying on the function I'm testing?

```
  it('should return error object when currentCount === 0', () => {
        spyOn(service, 'currentCount').and.returnValue(0);
        spyOn(ModValidation, 'require').and.returnValue({ 'isNotChecked' : true });
        service.currenCount();
        expect(ModValidation.require(service)).toEqual({ 'isNotChecked' : true });
    });
```

What I've tried, but doesn't work is:

```
  it('should return error object when currentCount === 0', () => {
        spyOn(service, 'currentCount').and.returnValue(0);
        const resp = ModValidation.require(service);
        service.currentCount();
        expect(resp).toEqual({ 'isNotChecked' : true });
    });
```

I get

```
Expected Function to equal Object({ isNotChecked: true }).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, that your require method within the validator is a function which transforms a AbstractControl into a validation result.

So what you would like to call is something like this:

```
it('currentCount 0', () => {
    const service = {currentCount: () => {}};
    spyOn(service, 'currentCount').and.returnValue(0);

    expect(CustomValidators.require(service)({} as any)).toEqual({
            'isNotChecked' : true
          });
  });
```

I made a Stackblitz for you to check: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/validator-test)

Comment: Just for a bit further explanation, this works, because your validation is independent of the AbstractControl input. If the validation would use the input control, to get the value, for example, you would need to pass in a mocked abstract control rather than `{} as any`. But anyway glad to help :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation